# What '%5rms' means in Log4Net ConfigurationFile?

Tags: logging, log4net

can anyone explain what %5rms means in ConversionPattern in Log4Net ConfigurationFile?

```
<conversionPattern value="%d %-5p [%thread](%c:%5rms) - %m %n" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%5` is a format specifier that means "use five spaces to display the text"

`r` [is defined as](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) "the number of milliseconds elapsed since the start of the application until the creation of the logging event."

`ms` is a literal string.

Sample results:

```
logger_name: 2015-12-21 10:55:31,035 ERROR [6](logger_name:   71ms) - log_message  
logger_name: 2015-12-21 10:55:31,042 ERROR [6](logger_name:   78ms) - log_message2  
logger_name: 2015-12-21 10:55:31,043 ERROR [6](logger_name:   79ms) - log_message3
```